# ListPicker, how to get the text from the selected item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to get the text from the selected item? How to assign a variable of type string text ListPicker?

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="EncodingList">
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="UTF-8" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Windows-1251" />
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get the text from the selected item?

The simplest way is:

```
var content = ((ListPickerItem)EncodingList.SelectedItem).Content;
```